# Dependency resolution configuration in Artifactory

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, artifactory

Recently we started to work with Artifactory. We configured settings.xml as Artifactory proposed. However we have problems downloading jars while running "mvn compile", even if they appear in Artifactory repo. Adding explicitly repo1-cache solves the compilation problem but download is performed from remote repository rather than from Artifactory.

```xml
<repository>
    <id>My Repository</id>
    <name>MyRepository-releases</name>
    <url>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
</repository>
```

What should be added to settings.xml in for resolving automatically dependencies and fetching them from artifactory rather than accessing remote servers each time?

#### settings.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>MyRepository</id>
    </server>
</servers>
```

#### Compilation error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.355s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 14 14:52:31 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project common: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myc
ompany.app:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: commons-jxpath:co
mmons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O-osgi, net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:
20080702-osgi, net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.9.0.4-osgi, net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:8.9.0.4-osgi, net.sf.
saxon:saxon-xqj:jar:8.9.0.4, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-imp
l:jar:2.1.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:2.1.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-remote:jar:2.1.1-osgi, com.yourkit:yjp-c
ontroller-api-redist:jar:9.0.8, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1-osgi, common
s-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3-osgi, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-osgi, quartz:quart
z-all:jar:1.6.6: Could not find artifact commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi in central (http
://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding to @duncan-jones excellent answer, great way to troubleshoot resolution is performing [Trace Artifact Retrieval](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#ArtifactorysRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval) call, in your case:

```
http://mvn-srv:8081/artifactory/libs-release/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3-osgi/commons-jxpath-1.3-osgi.jar?trace
```

BTW, I don't even see the 1.3-osgi version in [repo1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/).

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure your virtual repositories map to the real repositories you expect.

For example, `libs-release` will typically map to both internal and external release repositories. Perhaps this is mis-configured, resulting in it not hitting the repositories you want.

In Artifactory, go to the Admin page and look at *Configuration > Repositories*. At the bottom of the page, take a look at your virtual repositories. Double-clicking on them will show you what is included.

For me, `libs-release` includes `libs-release-local`, `ext-release-local` and `remote-repos`. The latter is another virtual repository that maps to all the external repositories listed in my installation, e.g. codehaus, repo1, jboss, google-code, ...

Perhaps one of these virtual repositories is missing `repo1`?